# Plural or singular noun: "Polish literature of the Positivist and Young Poland period(s)"

Tags: grammatical-number

My sentence is:

> **The article presents a comprehensive study of Polish literature of the Positivist and Young Poland period.**

Is this sentence correct? When listing two periods together, should I use 'periods' instead of 'period'? For the record: Positivism and Young Poland are names of movements/literary periods in Poland.

I am not a native English speaker and I've been staring at this sentence for so long...

Comment: Yes, two ranges of time are two periods. Only a paired time (the period that includes X and Y), or the Roaring and Modern Twenties, would form one period.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. So this means that the senetence should go: The article presents a comprehensive study of Polish literature of the Positivist and Young Poland periods.  If I understand correctly...

Comment: For readers who are not Polish, this would be easy to read "the Positivist and Young Poland period" as the single name of a single period. Pluralizing _periods_ indicates they are distinct.

Comment: Thank you! I have no more doubts :)

Comment: Now look what you have done! The asker is satisfied and so will go away without marking a correct answer. This fouls up our entire system here. The Q&A system cannot cope with answers in comments, and will not mark the question as answered if you do that. Answering in comments circumvents the very facilities that allow our Q&A community to police itself and maintain site quality.

Comment: @tchrist Cool. Now let's close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Literature from the Positivist and Young Poland periods.